# Robust method to apply Hebrew numeral in an enumeration list?

Tags: xetex, enumerate, enumitem, polyglossia

The difficult bit is that the enumitem package has a closed list of numbering formats, and that `\hebrewnumeral` is not part of them. I have

```
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\hebrewnumeral{\value{enumi}}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\theenumi}
```

but this is not so robust, e.g., it applies only to lists at the first level, and then there are issues of references to the list and more.

Any ideas on how the enumitem package can be hacked to do this?

Comment: Would not something like `\makeatletter
\def\hebnum#1{\expandafter\hebrewnumeral\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\AddEnumerateCounter{\hebnum}{\hebrewnumeral}{XXX}
\makeatother` work? Lifted from the enumitem docs sec.2.3, I don't know enough about the xetex mechanisms to try with proper hebrew stuff.

Comment: In the case that the document's main language is set to Hebrew via `babel`, a simple solution is given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/667888/21685).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to do it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{Corsiva Hebrew}
\setenumerate[1]{label=\texthebrew{\protect\hebrewnumeral{\value{enumi}}}}
\setenumerate[2]{label*=.\texthebrew{\protect\hebrewnumeral{\value{enumii}}}}
\setenumerate[3]{label*=.\texthebrew{\protect\hebrewnumeral{\value{enumiii}}}}
\setenumerate[4]{label*=.\texthebrew{\protect\hebrewnumeral{\value{enumiv}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
        \item A
        \item B
        \item \begin{enumerate}
                \item 1
                \item 2
                \item \begin{enumerate}
                        \item a
                        \item b
                        \item \begin{enumerate}
                                \item I
                                \item II
                                \item III
                        \end{enumerate}
                \end{enumerate}
        \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

If you set the language with

```
\setmainlanguage[numerals=hebrew]{hebrew}
```

all Arabic numerals will be replaced by Hebrew ones.

Comment: Alas, but one does not want *all* numerals to change. In English for example, it would make sense to change certain enumerations to (a), (b), (c), ..., but you do not usually want to pay the price of numbering your pages, figures, tables, theorems and sections with this scheme.