# Some problems using LyX RTL with equations

Tags: equations, lyx, enumerate, hebrew, right-to-left

I'm really new to the whole LyX(2.0.5.1) thing I'm usually using LibreOffice Writer and it's Latex like "formulas".

But I've heard so many good things about LyX, so I've decided to give it a try but I'm having some difficulties particularly when using Hebrew. Yes I've completed the tutorial, searched the Use guide, the internet and just tried to tinker with it but to no avail.
I'm trying write homework answers(view [image](http://postimage.org/image/6bije82et/)) that usually have the following format:

```
 1.
   a. (although it would be nice know how to replace this numbering with Hebrew letters).
```

The main problems are:

1. When generating a PDF it uses a very small portion of the page when in "Enumerate" area.
2. Equations that are too "long" for that tiny area are divided incorrectly as the Hebrew text is not "equal" to anything.
3. When I'm trying to use "Display Mode" the equation it simply cuts the equation.

I've added something that's supposed to be a MWE, I apologize if it's long but as I said I've been trying to use LyX only for a few days so I wouldn't really know which Latex parts are more important then the others.

% Preview source code

```
%% LyX 2.0.5.1 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english,hebrew]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9,cp1255]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{esint}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{theorem}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{theorem}{\R{משפט}}[section]
\AtBeginDocument{\make@lr\thetheorem}
\usepackage{enumitem}       % customizable list environments
\newlength{\lyxlabelwidth}      % auxiliary length 

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\title{ליקס}


\author{וקיפדיה}
\maketitle
\begin{enumerate}
\item רעיון הבסיסי של א שאין צורך לטפל בעיצוב. ישנה רשימה של עיצובים קיימים
וניתן לבחור מתוכה את אופי הטקסט (כותרת ראשית, כותרת משנית, הערת שוליים
וכו'). כך, התוצאה הסופית אמורה להיות עקבית ובעלת מראה מקצועי. בנוסף,
מא יבה נוחה של משוואות מתמטיות ולכן נפוץ בקרב קהילת האקדמאים העוסקים
במדעים מדויקים.
\item משתמש ב־ כמנגנון עיבוד הטקסט. \L{$\int\limits _{a}^{k}\int\limits _{0}^{\pi}2\pi\frac{\rho_{0}}{4\pi}\sin(\pi\frac{r-a}{b-a})\sin(\theta)d\theta dr=\int\limits _{a}^{k}\int\limits _{0}^{\pi}\frac{\rho_{0}}{2}\sin(\pi\frac{r-a}{b-a})\sin(\theta)d\theta dr=\rho_{0}\int\limits _{a}^{k}\sin(\pi\frac{r-a}{b-a})dr=\rho_{0}\left[-\cos\left(\pi\frac{r-a}{b-a}\right)\frac{b-a}{\pi}\right]_{a}^{k}$}היא
תוכנה ותיקה בעלת יכולות נרחבות, שבעזרתה ניתן להפיק מ־ יכול לייצא גם
\L{$\int\limits _{a}^{k}\int\limits _{0}^{\pi}2\pi\frac{\rho_{0}}{4\pi}\sin(\pi\frac{r-a}{b-a})\sin(\theta)d\theta dr=\int\limits _{a}^{k}\int\limits _{0}^{\pi}\frac{\rho_{0}}{2}\sin(\pi\frac{r-a}{b-a})\sin(\theta)d\theta dr=\rho_{0}\int\limits _{a}^{k}\sin(\pi\frac{r-a}{b-a})dr=\rho_{0}\left[-\cos\left(\pi\frac{r-a}{b-a}\right)\frac{b-a}{\pi}\right]_{a}^{k}$}
\item דורש מהמשתמש לימוד ארוך יחסית למעבד תמלילים דוגמת וורד אך מפיק בדרך
כלל תוצאות איכותיות יותר, ומאפשר עבודה מהירה יותר למשתמש המיומן.\L{
\begin{align*}
\int\limits _{a}^{k}\int\limits _{0}^{\pi}2\pi\frac{\rho_{0}}{4\pi}\sin(\pi\frac{r-a}{b-a})\sin(\theta)d\theta dr=\int\limits _{a}^{k}\int\limits _{0}^{\pi}\frac{\rho_{0}}{2}\sin(\pi\frac{r-a}{b-a})\sin(\theta)d\theta dr=\rho_{0}\int\limits _{a}^{k}\sin(\pi\frac{r-a}{b-a})dr=\rho_{0}\left[-\cos\left(\pi\frac{r-a}{b-a}\right)\frac{b-a}{\pi}\right]_{a}^{k} & s
\end{align*}
}\L{
\[
\int\limits _{a}^{k}\int\limits _{0}^{\pi}2\pi\frac{\rho_{0}}{4\pi}\sin(\pi\frac{r-a}{b-a})\sin(\theta)d\theta dr=\int\limits _{a}^{k}\int\limits _{0}^{\pi}\frac{\rho_{0}}{2}\sin(\pi\frac{r-a}{b-a})\sin(\theta)d\theta dr=\rho_{0}\int\limits _{a}^{k}\sin(\pi\frac{r-a}{b-a})dr=\rho_{0}\left[-\cos\left(\pi\frac{r-a}{b-a}\right)\frac{b-a}{\pi}\right]_{a}^{k}
\]
}\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Thanks, I've tried to fix some things but I guess a .lyx file is not a valid MWE? or is it?

Comment: Welcome! First of all, LaTeX (which is generated by LyX) is very different from LibreOffice Writer. Along your explorations of LyX, my suggestion is to get an overview of how LaTeX works (e.g. [The (Not So) Short Introduction to LaTeX2e](http://ctan.tug.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf)). Then you will better understand the background of LyX, which generates LaTeX...

Comment: Second, you can select "View > View Source" from the menu -- a new window will open -- and there select "Complete Source". This is the LaTeX source that LyX generates to create your PDF. Alternatively, "File > Export > LaTeX (pdflatex)" will put the code into a file with extension `.tex`. Then you can post either one but keep in mind to shorten your LyX document as much as possible first (since we like *minimal* working examples).

Comment: Third, that are several questions in one. Consider to make one post per question... To Question 1. That seems alright that enumerations are more indented... (But without a MWE - the picture seems not to show that -  it is hard to say). To Quesiton 2 and 3. It seems that you have to break the equations by using several math environments. For display mode, also "Insert > Math > AMS align Environment" might be helpful.

Comment: I've tried Using AMS align didn't work.

Comment: @SadStudent Please use `@e-birk` to notify. Otherwise I will not see your comment. It just happened that I was writing an answer anyway. -- Let's see. Can you try below approach? Does it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elaborating my comment to an answer...

**Question 1: "Enumerate" uses small portion of the page.**

Answer: If you use enumerations in LyX / LaTeX, I guess, it does not matter whether you use a right-to-left or a left-to-right language, the indentation will always be the same amount (of course, on the right side if using right-to-left). LaTeX (which is generated by LyX) uses typesetting rules that are quite professional. You will also see that an average line (at least in English) has about 65 characters and thus, a quite big margin might be left. This limit on the length of a line is used for better readability. Here is an example.

[image: indentation of enumeration]

The example was simply created by using a new LyX document with

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
```

put into "Document > Settings... > LaTeX Preamble" and

```
\blindtext \blindlistlist[2]{enumerate}[2] \blindtext
```

put as TeX code/ERT (`<Crtl>-L`) in the main document. (Note that the LaTeX package `blindtext` is used.)

**Question 1a: How to replace this numbering with Hebrew letters.**

Answer: As a quick workaround you can use the description environment instead. Then you should be able to put any label you want. (Furthermore, nesting of enumerations, itemizations, descriptions is possible in LyX.)

[image: description environment]

Otherwise see [Robust method to apply Hebrew numeral in an enumeration list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10931/robust-method-to-apply-hebrew-numeral-in-an-enumeration-list) (Possibly you need ask a separate question how to integrate that in LyX...)

**Question 2: Long equations are divided incorrectly...**

Answer: LaTeX break equations not at arbitrary points but usually after relation symbols. If you do not like the break up then - as a workaround - you can split the inline math environment into two or more.

You might also search on this site for [questions tagged with math-mode and line-breaking](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math-mode+line-breaking).

**Question 3: The equation is cut in "Display Mode".**

Answer: A common way to deal with long formulas and many equations is to use "Insert > Math > AMS align Environment". Then you can add rows and break up the equations over several lines. It looks like in the following picture.

[image: AMS align Environment in LyX]

Comment: thanks for the ideas, additionally I've found out that using the fullpage package allows me to get the extra wide margins that I was after.

Answer (score 2):

I also suggest that you split your question into several different questions. And I'm not much of a LyX guy. However...

- That doesn't really have much to do with the Enumerate environment. It just takes a little more than what are alread pretty wide margins. You might try `\usepackage{fullpage}` for smaller margins (or check out the [geometry package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) for complete control of margins, spacing and such).
- About the reversed parentheses: In LyX, this is a known bug with a patch, see [here](http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/8251): It's supposed to switch the direction of the parentheses for you, but doesn't. Are you using LyX 2.0.5 or higher? If you're working with LaTeX directly (e.g. the exported LaTeX), see [this question([Right-to-left text in LaTeX - reversed numbers and parentheses](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38421/5640)) and specifically, [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38505/5640).
- As for math equations overflowing - this is a problem in general, not just with right-to-left languages or with LyX. If LyX doesn't offer to arrange display-mode math for you somehow, consider doing it yourself, after reading [section 3.5 of the not-so-short into to LaTeX](http://ctan.tug.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf).

Comment: I'm using 2.0.5.1...