# How to make an enumerated list's numbering alphabetic per the Hebrew alphabet?

Tags: enumerate, enumitem, hebrew

How can an `enumerate` list's items have alphabetic item marks per the Hebrew alphabet: not `A`, `B`, `C`, etc., but `א`, `ב`, `ג`, etc.?

I'd like to have several types of `enumerate` lists in my document. Some numeric, some alphabetic per the English alphabet, and some alphabetic per the Hebrew alphabet.

Another requirement is that the solution must be compatible with `babel`/`lualatex`.

As a minimal working example, consider the following LaTeX code, saved in `~/Test.tex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\begin{document}
A numeric list:
\begin{enumerate}
\item First item
\item Second item
\item Third item
\end{enumerate}

An alphabetic list with capital English list-labels:
\begin{enumerate}[A.]
\item First item
\item Second item
\item Third item
\end{enumerate}

An alphabetic list with lowercase English list-labels:
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item First item
\item Second item
\item Third item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

When the following commands are executed in the Terminal:

```
> cd ~
> lualatex Test
```

the file `~/Test.pdf` is created. When opened in a PDF viewer, the file displays as follows. (I screenshot only the relevant part of the display.)

[image: Lists with various item symbols]

I'd like the third list to have `(א)`, `(ב)`, and `(ג)` instead of `(a)`, `(b)`, and `(c)` as the item marks, and I'd like the list to accommodate potentially many (let's say, forty) items, not just three.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Robust method to apply Hebrew numeral in an enumeration list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10931/robust-method-to-apply-hebrew-numeral-in-an-enumeration-list)

Comment: @Marijn No, it does not. The question you linked to is the same as mine, but the answers provided to it are inadequate. As I mentioned in my post, I'd like to have several kinds of numbering schemas in my document: numeric, English, and Hebrew. Furthermore, as indicated in my post, I'd like to be able to adorn the Hebrew numerals on an ad-hoc basic in the same way that English numerals can be adorned, say with a dot --- A. B. C. --- or parentheses --- (A) (B) (C) --- etc.

Comment: BTW I'm sure my question has wide applicability. I've seen books and articles in languages such as Arabic and Russian that use alphabetic numerics based on the Arabic/Cyrillic alphabet, respectively.

Comment: A hint. With `babel` and `hebrew` as the current language, `\begin{enumerate}[label=(\protect\localecounter{letters}{enumi})]`.

Comment: @JavierBezos Thanks. This is helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let’s go by steps.

#### Hebrew numerals

`babel` defines a good deal of numerals, including the Hebrew additive numerals. There is a partial list [here](https://latex3.github.io/babel/news/whats-new-in-babel-3.41.html), and we must add the native numerals. A common and consistent interface is provided with `\localenumeral` and `\localecounter`, which is explained in that link. There is an example in [GitHub](https://github.com/latex3/babel/blob/main/samples/numerals.pdf), but here is simple document, which prints “ג—א”:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[bidi=basic, hebrew, provide=*]{babel}
\babelfont{rm}{FreeSerif}

\begin{document}

\localenumeral{letters}{3}—\localecounter{letters}{page}

\end{document}
```

New numerals can be defined easily, as explained in [How to define counters with arbitrary alphabet](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529813/how-to-define-counters-with-arbitrary-alphabet/530491#530491).

Do *not* rely on the old `\hebrewnumeral`. Except for `pdftex`, it’s use should be considered deprecated with `babel` + `xetex`/`luatex`.

#### Locale dependent alphabetic numeral

The counters `\alph` and `\Alph` can be easily customized in a locale dependent way with a key in `\babelprovide`. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[bidi=basic, hebrew, provide=*]{babel}
\babelprovide[Alph=letters]{hebrew}
\babelfont{rm}{FreeSerif}

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[A)]
\item First
\item Second
\end{enumerate}

\selectlanguage{english}

\begin{enumerate}[A)]
\item First
\item Second
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Customize enumerate labels

Currently ‘decorators’ must be handled by hand. There is a tool for this, namely `\AddBabelHook`, which allows to inject code when a language is selected. There are two in the following example: the first one sets `\mylabel` ‘globally’, while the second one redefines it for `hebrew`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[bidi=basic, hebrew, provide=*]{babel}
\babelfont{rm}{FreeSerif}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\mylabel}{[\alph{enumi}]}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\mylabel}

\AddBabelHook{lists}{afterextras}{% 
  \renewcommand{\mylabel}{[\alph{enumi}]}}
\AddBabelHook[hebrew]{lists}{afterextras}{% 
  \renewcommand{\mylabel}{\protect\localecounter{letters}{enumi})}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item First
\end{enumerate}

\selectlanguage{english}

\begin{enumerate}
\item First
\end{enumerate}

\selectlanguage{hebrew}

\begin{enumerate}
\item First
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Final remark

Hebrew does *not* have to the main language for the numerals to work. It can be even a secondary language loaded on the fly:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[bidi=basic, french]{babel}
\babelfont{rm}{FreeSerif}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item First
\item Second
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\foreignlanguage{hebrew}{\protect\localecounter{letters}{enumi}})]
\item First
\item Second
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Using [Robust method to apply Hebrew numeral in an enumeration list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10931/robust-method-to-apply-hebrew-numeral-in-an-enumeration-list) as a basis the procedure is as follows:

- load Polyglossia for `\hebrewnumeral`, as in the other question
- redefine the label using `enumitem`, as in the other question
- but use the modern syntax `\setlist` given that `\setenumerate` is deprecated
- to be able to use various types of list in the same document, either set the default to Hebrew and specify `\begin{enumerate}[1.]` for numeric lists,

or

- define a new list type for Hebrew and set the counter to Hebrew only for this list type, as in the MWE below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\hebfont[Script=Hebrew, Scale=MatchUppercase, Ligatures=TeX]{Noto Serif Hebrew}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\newlist{hebenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[hebenum,1]{
   labelindent=\parindent,
   label={{\hebfont{\protect\hebrewnumeral{\value{hebenumi}}}}.}
}

\begin{document}
A numeric list:
\begin{enumerate}
\item First item
\item Second item
\item Third item
\end{enumerate}

An alphabetic list with capital English list-labels:
\begin{enumerate}[A.]
\item First item
\item Second item
\item Third item
\end{enumerate}

Hebrew list labels:
\begin{hebenum}[1.]
\item First item
\item Second item
\item Third item
\end{hebenum}

An alphabetic list with lowercase English list-labels:
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item First item
\item Second item
\item Third item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

The following is a version that works with Babel instead of Polyglossia. Actually the code for `\hebrewnumeral` from Polyglossia was originally developed for Babel in the file `hebrew.ldf`. However, modern versions of Babel don't load `hebrew.ldf` anymore because of incompatibilities. Therefore, a workaround is to load *only* the Polyglossia version of the Babel code for `\hebrewnumeral` without loading Polyglossia itself.

An additional improvement can be made by writing a small macro `\hebnum` to perform the conversion and calling that macro using `\hebnum*` within an enumerate specification. This means it is no longer necessary to use a special list and you can also fully customize the counter with parentheses or other punctuation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english,bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=he]{hebrew}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\input{babel-hebrewalph.def}
\makeatother
\newfontfamily\hebfont[Script=Hebrew, Scale=MatchUppercase, Ligatures=TeX]{Noto Serif Hebrew}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\newcommand{\hebnum}[1]{%
\begingroup%
\hebfont{\protect\hebrewnumeral{\value{#1}}}%
\endgroup%
}
\begin{document}
A numeric list:
\begin{enumerate}
\item First item
\item Second item
\item Third item
\end{enumerate}

An alphabetic list with capital English list-labels:
\begin{enumerate}[A.]
\item First item
\item Second item
\item Third item
\end{enumerate}

Hebrew list labels:
\begin{enumerate}[(\hebnum*)]
\item First item
\item Second item
\item Third item
\end{enumerate}

An alphabetic list with lowercase English list-labels:
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item First item
\item Second item
\item Third item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that the solution hinted by Javier Bezos is better/more robust.

Comment: Thanks. I've added the requirement that the solution must be compatible with `babel`/`lualatex`.

Comment: @EvanAad It is compatible with LuaLaTeX already (the other question was about XeLaTeX but the solution works for LuaLaTeX too without any changes). It can probably be made compatible with Babel (which you did not state initially as a requirement), Polyglossia is only used for `\hebrewnumeral` but I'm sure similar functionality is available for Babel.

Comment: I can't accept an answer that is incompatible with `babel`/`lualatex` as written.

Comment: That's ok, I will see if I can find a Babel replacement for `\hebrewnumeral`.

Comment: @EvanAad I added a Babel version, however it is not very clean, so it would probably be better to pursue to approach given by Javier Bezos.

Comment: @EvanAad I simplified the code a bit and added the possibility to customize the counter using the standard `\begin{enumerate}[some format]` syntax.

Comment: @JavierBezos: Does `babel` provide a command similar to `polyglossia`'s `\hebrewnumerals`, so that Marijn's answer can be written simpler?

Comment: @Marijn Don’t, please. Combining `polyglossia` and `babel` is a bad idea and the latter provides an alternative to `\hebrewnumerals`. See my answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/668034/5735.

Comment: @JavierBezos I understand that mixing Babel and Polyglossia is a bad idea, however the file that is loaded in this answer (babel-hebrewalph.def) contains very little if any Polyglossia code as far as I can see. It is basically only the definition of `\hebrewnumeral`, which is/was Babel code in the first place. While I completely agree that your answer is cleaner, I don't necessarily think that my answer is by definition a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something else that works, though it is XeLaTeX-based, and font-specific (with an added mystery). But it is would be adaptable to other fonts in your system. The bit of code is taken from
[How to print Unicode characters in LaTeX by its code? (For example \U0001316E)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/530483/how-to-print-unicode-characters-in-latex-by-its-code-for-example-u0001316e).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newfontfamily{\hefont}{AdobeHebrew-Regular}
\begin{document}
alef = {\hefont \char"05D0} \quad bet = {\hefont \char"05D1}, etc.

\begin{enumerate}[left= \parindent .. 2\parindent, label=({\hefont \char"05D\arabic*})]
    \item\label{a} Hello
    \item\label{b} Test
    \item\label{c} QRZ?
    \item\label{d} Hey!
\end{enumerate}

\ref{a}\quad \ref{b} \quad \ref{c}\quad \ref{d}
\end{document}
```

So you need to have a typeface with the desired glyphs installed in your system, and you need the to have the Unicode codes for the the Hebrew alphabet available. And, they need to be in ascending order.

The key line is `label=({\hefont \char"05D\arabic*})`. The `()` create the parenthesis styling (so change it to `label={\hefont \char"05D\arabic*}.)` for items with a trailing period), `\hefont` changes the typeface to Adobe Hebrew, and `\char"05D\arabic*` generates the sequence of codes 05D0, 05D1, etc. The mystery here is it started with 0; I was expecting to need a reset of the counter to -1 to get 0 as the first value of counter enumi.

Other thing that is perhaps good is that the cross-referencing works as-is. Hope this is useable.

Comment: Thanks. I've added the requirement that the LaTeX compiler must be `lualatex`.

Comment: Additionally, a solution that relies on a specific font is unacceptable.

Comment: Two extra comments: I just ran it through LuaLaTeX on my system (never tried it before), and it ran as-is. Second, if you are using multiple Hebrew typefaces, you could create multiple `\newfontfamily` commands, I suppose. My specific choice was only based on what was on my personal system. Just trying to save face here...

Comment: Having to manually specify the item number for every item is unacceptable.

Answer (score 1):

The following answer is based on [Javier Bezos' comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/667874/how-to-make-an-enumerated-lists-item-marks-alphabetic-per-the-hebrew-alphabet/667888#comment1660431_667874). It only works when Hebrew is set, via `babel`, to be the document's main language.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bidi=basic,hebrew,provide=*]{babel}
\babelfont{rm}[Renderer=HarfBuzz]{FreeSans}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand{\HeNum}{\protect\localenumeral{letters}{\value*}}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\HeNum)]
   \item The woods are lovely
   \item Dark and deep
   \item But I have promises to keep
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: An enumerated list with Hebrew numerals as the item numbering marks]

---

It would be nice if there were some command similar to `babel`'s `\localenumeral` that would work even when `babel` were not loaded, as well as when `babel` were loaded, but the document's language were not set to Hebrew.

Put differently, I wish that the definition of `\HeNum` given above would work and yield the same output as shown (except for alignment and direction of text flow) even if the lines

```
\usepackage[bidi=basic,hebrew,provide=*]{babel}
\babelfont{rm}[Renderer=HarfBuzz]{FreeSans}
```

were missing, and even if the line

```
\usepackage[bidi=basic,hebrew,provide=*]{babel}
```

were replaced by, say, `\usepackage[french]{babel}`.