# How to make an enumerated list's numbering alphabetic per the Hebrew alphabet, in a Hebrew beamer presentation?

Tags: beamer, enumerate, enumitem, hebrew, right-to-left

The following question can be seen as a continuation of [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/667874/21685) to the case that the document class is `beamer` rather than `article`.

Inside a Hebrew presentation I wish to have the (non mandatory!) option to set the numbering of an enumerated list as alphabetic per the Hebrew alphabet, i.e. instead of `A`, `B`, `C`, etc., `א`, `ב`, `ג`, etc.

---

**An attempt at a solution**

Consider the following LaTeX code, which is essentially copied from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/667888/21685), with small modifications.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[import,main]{hebrew}
\babelfont{rm}[Renderer=HarfBuzz]{FreeSans}

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\newcommand{\HeNum}{\protect\localenumeral{letters}{\value*}}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\HeNum]
   \item The woods are lovely
   \item Dark and deep
   \item But I have promises to keep
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

When the following commands are executed in the Terminal:

```
> cd ~
> lualatex Test
```

the file `~/Test.pdf` is created. When opened in a PDF viewer, the file displays as follows. (I screenshot only the relevant part of the display.)

[image: A Hebrew list in an article]

I wish to deploy this trick in a Hebrew `beamer` presentation. I used the following presentation as a starting point. The presentation was saved in `~/Test.tex`, replacing this file's previous content.

```
\documentclass{beamer-rl}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[import,main]{hebrew}
\babelprovide[import]{english}
\babelfont{rm}[Renderer=HarfBuzz]{FreeSerif}
\babelfont{sf}[Renderer=HarfBuzz]{FreeSans}
\babelfont{tt}[Renderer=HarfBuzz]{FreeMono}

%\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
%\newcommand{\HeNum}{\protect\localenumeral{letters}{\value*}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}[A]
   \item The woods are lovely
   \item Dark and deep
   \item But I have promises to keep
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Executing the same commands as before, the file `~/Test.pdf` was replaced by one that contained a single slide which displayed as follows. (I screenshot only the relevant part of the display.)

[image: A Hebrew beamer presentation with an enumerated list]

Note how the list items' labels are stylized in accordance with the presentation's theme.

I now uncommented the two commented lines, and replaced the `enumerate` environment's option list by the following: `[label=\HeNum]`, as in the first example in which the document class was `article`. The resulting PDF file contained a single slide that displayed as follows. (I screenshot only the relevant part of the display.)

[image: A Hebrew presentation with a Hebrew enumerated list]

Note that the list items' labels are no longer stylized.

Why are the list items' labels not stylized? How can the styling be restored?

---

I'm looking for a general solution, that doesn't assume the theme is `Warsaw` necessarily. Ideally, the solution should also be simple and natural, as in the case of the `article` document class. Ideally, I shouldn't need to "restore" the styling; I could merely instruct an enumerated list to use Hebrew numerals, possibly with adornments (e.g. a dot following the letter, or a pair of parentheses surrounding the letter), and the magic would happen automatically, as it does when English alphabetic numerals are used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can not use `enumitem` with `beamer`: As you saw it overwrites various beamer commands and so destroys the look and also overlay specification.

`beamer` loads the `enumerate`  package which allows to select the numbering scheme, but only from a fix set. You could extend this set by redefining an internal command:

```
\documentclass{beamer-rl}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[import,main]{hebrew}
\babelprovide[import]{english}
\babelfont{rm}[Renderer=HarfBuzz]{FreeSerif}
\babelfont{sf}[Renderer=HarfBuzz]{FreeSans}
\babelfont{tt}[Renderer=HarfBuzz]{FreeMono}


\newcommand{\HeNum}[1]{\localenumeral{letters}{\value{#1}}}

\makeatletter
\pretocmd\@enloop@{\ifx H\@entemp \def\@tempa{\@enLabel\HeNum }\else}{}{\fail}
\patchcmd\@enloop@{\fi}{\fi\fi}{}{\fail}
\makeatother  
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}[H]
   \item The woods are lovely
   \item Dark and deep
   \item But I have promises to keep
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[A]
   \item The woods are lovely
   \item Dark and deep
   \item But I have promises to keep
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is splendid!

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the `enumitem` package with beamer, they are not compatible.

Instead you can redefine the appropriate beamer template. For example for enumerate ball items:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass{beamer-rl}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[import,main]{hebrew}
\babelprovide[import]{english}
\babelfont{rm}[Renderer=HarfBuzz]{FreeSerif}
\babelfont{sf}[Renderer=HarfBuzz]{FreeSans}
\babelfont{tt}[Renderer=HarfBuzz]{FreeMono}


\defbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{foo}
{
  \begin{pgfpicture}{-1ex}{-0.65ex}{1ex}{1ex}
    \usebeamercolor{item projected}
    {\pgftransformscale{1.75}\pgftext{\normalsize\pgfuseshading{bigsphere}}}
    {\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0.5pt}}
      \pgftext{%
        \usebeamerfont*{item projected}%
        \color{fg}\protect\localenumeral{letters}{\theenumi}}}
  \end{pgfpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begingroup
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}[foo]
\begin{enumerate}
   \item The woods are lovely
   \item Dark and deep
   \item But I have promises to keep
\end{enumerate}
\endgroup
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this solution doesn't satisfy the requirements in my post. The Hebrew enumeration must be optional, so that in the same presentation I could have one enumerated list that is alphabetic per the Hebrew alphabet, another one that is alphabetic per the English alphabet, and a third one that is numeric. Furthermore, as I stated in my question, I would like to be able to add adornments to the numbering, on an ad hoc basis, e.g. `(א)`, `(ב)`, `(ג)`, etc.  And what about nested lists? Your solution fails with a nested list.

Comment: As mentioned in my post, a good solution would work naturally and seamlessly, just like alphabetic enumerated lists do w.r.t. the English alphabet.

Comment: Beamer templates are optional. You can switch them on/off however you like. You can redefine subitems in the same way.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is a bad solution. I should not have to redefine a list together with its bullet point, etc, and tweak the scale and shift and whatnot. just because I want the numbering to be per the Hebrew alphabet. It is not less preposterous than it would be to force a person to redefine an enumerated list if they wanted to switch to an alphabetic enumeration based on the English alphabet, instead of simply giving the option `A` to the `enumerate` environment.

Comment: Wouldn't `\renewcommand\insertenumlabel{\localenumeral{letters}{\value{enumi}}}` be simpler?

Comment: @EvanAad You are using a free software maintained by people in their free time. So check your tone a bit. The support for bidi is sketchy in various places, but you will get nowhere by simply claiming that it should be otherwise. If you want better support for bidi and are not satisfied about what currently is done: find someone willing and skilled enough to do more.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, that would work too. I just like templates as this allows to easily switch between different behaviours during the presentation. I'd be happy to see your solution as an answer!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You are right. I appologize to samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz for my tone. Thank you, Sam, for your answer. Even if it's not perfect, it's better than nothing.